# Plotly: Some gridlines are thicker than others?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

Is it just me or are some gridlines thicker than others?

[image: screenshots saved in ms paint]

If you look at the top plot, the vertical lines at 3.5 and 4 seem thicker than the other vertical lines. And the lines at 12.5 and 13.5 seem thicker than the other horizontal lines. In the plot below, you see the same for vertical 10 and horizontal 20 and 25. You can see this inconsistency in [any other plot.](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/)

Is this just an optical illusion? If not, how can I make them consistent?

**Edit:** Taking a screenshot of the graphs changes the perceived thick lines, some previously thick lines become normal and some new lines get thicker. This leads me to believe this is just an optical illusion. Baffling nonetheless.

**Edit 2:** Here's an indepth look. This is from [plotly's documentation](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/) page itself. You can see in the image the line in the lower plot is two pixels long. (The pixel reading is that of the line to the immediate left of it)

[image: screenshots of firefox browser itself]

**Edit 3:** Here's more screenshots of my chrome browser and from my android phone. These too show inconsistencies in thickness.

[image: chrome screenshots]

Android-

[image: android screenshots]

**Edit 4:** Resizing the window changes the thickness of the lines, makes some thicker whilst making others thinner.

Also, checked plotly docs on a mac. Lines were consistent with same thickness.

Comment: I'm sorry, but they look identical to me. It might just be your display or some illusion for you.

Comment: @SamarthBhatia I see those exact lines darker on my phone.

Comment: I think this is some display / compression artifact that you're seeing. The plots in the linked page look just fine. The lines in your plot do, indeed look thicker - about 1px thicker, and this is most likely a compression artifact.

Comment: @SiHa For me, the plots on the linked page too look like they have inconsistent grid lines.

Edit: I checked and they are indeed 1 pixel thicker for me in the linked documentation too.

Comment: @SiHa Added pixel level image comparison, straight from the documentation in my firefox browser.

Comment: I have the same issue in my local environment using `plotly.graph_objects`, but after outputting the image, the grid lines are consistent.

Comment: I observe the same thing. I hosted the graphs on a website and they render just fine there.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely something in your local environment.

I open the plotly page you linked above (in Chrome), take a screenshot and paste into mspaint (so direct bitmap paste - no compression) and can see that all gridlines are 1px wide, except for the
axes, which are 2px.

[image]

I'm almost 100% certain that what you're seeing here is an aliasing effect caused by the image compression. As a test - try exporting the charts as BMP, or even a higher resolution jpg/png, and I'm fairly confident you won't see this.

Comment: I measured the pixel width of the lines without taking a screenshot, straight from the browser and yet it showed me a thicker line. I'll try doing the same in chrome.

To be more clear, the 2nd edit is a screenshot of the browser itself.

Comment: Huh. Odd. Regardless, I still believe it's your environment, not plotly, that's causing this.

Comment: I believe so too. But I also checked on more browsers and devices. Made 2 edits regarding the same.